# Usar SCOPE_IDENTITY para traer el ID de un insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, entity-framework

Tengo una tabla usuarios donde al agregar un usuario le puedo asignar varios hoteles, que es otro `insert` a una tabla de muchos a muchos. Investigando un poco puedo usar el `scope_identity()` para poder realizar esto ya que me trae el ultimo registro de la sesión actual pero leyendo acerca de el no se como usarlo o aplicarlo en mi codigo.

¿Comó puedo aplicarlo con Linq o con Entity Frammework? ¿Existe alguna alternativa?

Aquí mi `ActionResult` donde hago el insert. Solo agrego un usuario aun no logro encontrar como agregar los multiples hoteles ya que necesito el id del usuario insertado.

```
 public ActionResult CrEd([Bind(Include = "IdUsuario,Nombre,Contrasena,Descripcion,Estatus,IdRol")] Usuarios usuarios, int? bandera)
        {
            if(bandera == 1)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Usuarios.Add(usuarios);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                ViewBag.IdRol = new SelectList(db.UsuariosRol, "IdRol", 

"Nombre", usuarios.IdRol);
                    return View(usuarios);
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando haces un `context.Entity.Add(entity)` y luego un `context.SaveChanges()`, entity framework ejecuta un `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` y le asigna el valor a la propiedad que esta marcada con el atributo [[Key]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Supongamos que tu entidad Usuarios tenga una propiedad Id marcada con el atributo Key:

```
public class Usuarios
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set;}

  //...
}
```

Entonces al guardar:

```
   db.Usuarios.Add(usuarios);
   db.SaveChanges();
   int scope_identity_id = usuarios.Id; // id tendra el id asignado por la base de datos
```