# Guardar datos en 2 tablas con el id de otra tabla

Tags: base-de-datos, asp.net

Amigos como están, estoy tratando de guardar datos en 3 tablas a la vez, Consulta, Diagnostico y Tratamiento; los datos que se tienen que guardar se encuentran en una misma vista y se guardan todos a la vez cuando le doy en guardar, pero los datos en las tablas Diagnostico y Tratamiento deben guardarse con el id de Consulta. He estado tratando de realizar el guardado almacenando el ID de consulta en una variable y luego pasarlo a las demas tablas, pero aun no me guarda aun los datos en las tablas....

[image: Tablas]

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Guardar(ConsultaCLS oConsulta)
        {           
            try
            {
                using (UCSM_v2Context db = new UCSM_v2Context())
                {
                    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        return View(oConsulta);
                    }
                    else
                    {                        
                        Consultum objeto = new Consultum();
                        TratamientoEnfermedad objeto2 = new TratamientoEnfermedad();
                        Diagnostico objeto3 = new Diagnostico();
                        objeto.Id = oConsulta.iidconsulta;
                        objeto.Idpersona = oConsulta.idEntidad;
                        objeto.Idestado = 1;
                        objeto.Observaciones = oConsulta.motivo;
                        objeto.Imagen = oConsulta.imagen;
                        objeto.Fecha = DateTime.Now;
                        objeto.Estadoregistro = "1";
                        db.Consulta.Add(objeto);
                        db.TratamientoEnfermedads.Add(objeto2);
                        db.Diagnosticos.Add(objeto3);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        var iddeConsulta = objeto.Id;
                        var iddeTratamiento = objeto2.Id;
                        var iddeDiagnostico = objeto3.Id;

                        var consultaObj = db.Consulta.First(x => x.Id == iddeConsulta);
                        consultaObj.Id = iddeTratamiento;
                        consultaObj.Id = iddeDiagnostico;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        
                        objeto2.Idconsulta = iddeTratamiento;
                        objeto2.Descripcion = oConsulta.tratamiento;
                        objeto2.FechaInicio = DateTime.Now;
                        objeto2.FechaFin = oConsulta.finTratamiento;
                        objeto2.FechaModificacion = DateTime.Now;
                        objeto2.UsuarioModificacion = "user";
                        objeto2.EstadoRegistro = true;
                        objeto3.Idconsulta = iddeDiagnostico;
                        objeto3.DiagPrimario = oConsulta.diagnostico;
                        objeto3.Fecha = DateTime.Now;
                        objeto3.Estadoregistro = "1";
                        db.SaveChanges();                        

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View(oConsulta);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        

<form asp-controller="Consulta" asp-action="Guardar" method="post">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <input asp-for="idEntidad" class="form-control" type="hidden" id="idEntidad" />
        <input asp-for="iidconsulta" class="form-control" value="0" type="hidden" id="iidconsulta" />
        <input asp-for="fechaNac" class="form-control" id="fechaNac" min="01-01-1930" style="display:none" />
        <div class="col-10">
            <label asp-for="nombre" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="nombre" class="form-control" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="edad" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="edad" class="form-control" id="edad" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label asp-for="motivo" class="control-label"></label>
            <textarea asp-for="motivo" class="form-control" rows="5" id="foo"></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="motivo" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" form-row col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="diagnostico" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="idenfermedad" id="single" class="form-control form-control-chosen" asp-items="@lista"></select>               
                <textarea asp-for="diagnostico" class="form-control col-md-12 mt-2" rows="8" id="diagnos"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="tratamiento" class="control-label"></label>
                <textarea asp-for="tratamiento" class="form-control col-md-12" rows="8" id="foo"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="tratamiento" class="text-danger"></span>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mt-2">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <label asp-for="finTratamiento" class="input-group-text"></label>
                    </div>                    
                    <input asp-for="finTratamiento" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary" />    
        <a class="btn btn-danger" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Consulta">Cancelar</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque no intentas hacer dicha acción  mediante entorno BD, con ayuda de un trigger INSERT puedes lograr capturar el id luego de inserción el Consulta,realizar  sentencias IF de acuerdo a los datos de consulta para guardarlo en  la tabla de Diagnostico y tratamiento?

Comment: Evita dejar comentarios en la zonas de respuesta, espera a que tengas la reputación necesaria para poder comentar, date una vuelta en [answer].

Comment: La respuesta la encontré en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90227/usar-scope-identity-para-traer-el-id-de-un-insert